# Studying musical Harmony I have the problem of summing sinus lines with angles in geometric progression

Tags: trigonometric-series

$$\sum_{i=0}^n\cos(\omega_0\cdot2^{i/12})$$
When we put successively $i=0,4,3$ we have a major chord.
But what is an analytic expression for this limited sum?

Comment: The sum given at the beginning of this question is $$ 1 + \cos(\omega_0\cdot 2^{1/12}) + \cos(\omega_0\cdot 2^{2/12}) + \cos(\omega_0\cdot 2^{3/12}) + \cos(\omega_0\cdot 2^{4/12}) + \cdots + \cos(\omega_0\cdot 2^{n/12}) $$ The sum $$\cos(\omega_0\cdot 2^{0/12}) + \cos(\omega_0\cdot 2^{3/12}) + \cos(\omega_0\cdot 2^{7/12}) $$ is not an instance of that. Might it be that instead of $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^n$ you meant $\displaystyle \sum_{i\,\in\, I}$ where $I$ is some specified set of integers? $\vphantom{\frac{\displaystyle\sum} {}} \qquad$

Comment: In addition to Michael Hardy's comment, did you mean $i=0,4,7$ for a major chord?

Comment: Usually, we do it the other way around!  We start with a musical tone, then decompose it into a linear combination of trig functions, since that is much simpler to do calculations with.

Comment: I agree with your remarks due to the fact I met some problems to use the math editor. The first answer I hope, brings about the major chord formula , which in turn treats the simple problem of summing three trigonometric lines.